# Find largest TRUE row number of each column in Matlab

Tags: image, matlab, binary

I have a binary image `BW`, and I want to find out the largest row number of each column. I know I can do it in a loop, and in each iteration I return `max(find(BW(:,i)));` as the row number in column `i`. But is there some simpler method to achieve this?

Note all the true values in `BW` are connected, I guess this may simplify the search process.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do the following vectorized thing instead. I think that's 30 characters.

```
  [~,idx]=max(flipud(BW), [], 1);

  result=(size(BW,1)+1) - idx;
```

Comment: very smart approach! Thank you!

Comment: It assumes there is at least one TRUE in each column. Otherwise, you'll need additional processing.

Comment: Hello Matt J, I asked another array question, and would like to listen to your suggestions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21342609/find-out-the-largest-element-from-the-given-row-to-the-end  Thank you