# find out the largest element from the given row to the end

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

Suppose I have a matrix a and a given row number list for each column:

```
>> a=magic(5)

>> a =

    17    24     1     8    15
    23     5     7    14    16
     4     6    13    20    22
    10    12    19    21     3
    11    18    25     2     9

>> b=[2 3 4 5 1];  %% Note that the elements in b is arbitrary
```

Now I want to find the maximal values from column `1`, row `2:end`,and column `2`, row `3:end`, ... ,and column `5`, row `1:end` respectively, is there a method without using for-loop? I tried `a(b:end,:)` but it starts all from `b(1)` for each column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set non-wanted entries to `NaN` and then use `max`:

```
ind = bsxfun(@lt, (1:size(a,1)).', b); %'// logical index
a(ind) = NaN; %// set those entries to NaN
result = max(a); %// compute maximum of each column
```

This works for arbitrary `b` (not necessarily in diagonal form).

Comment: Thank you! Can you please explain the .' after (1:size(a,1))? Is it a transpose?

Comment: @ChuNan Yes, it's a transpose. First vector in `bsxfun` is a column (thanks to the tranpose), second is a row, so that bsxfun does the computation for all combinations (that is, for the full matrix size)

Comment: @ChuNan Welcome! Good question by the way, +1

Answer (score 1):

Here is another possibility using arrayfun:

```
res = arrayfun(@(n) max(a(b(n):end,n)),1:numel(b))
```

Answer (score 0):

diagonal?

```
 [m n] = size(a); 
 [tril(a(:,1:n-1),-1), a(:,n)]
```

then

```
max([tril(a(:,1:n-1),-1), a(:,n)])
```

result

> 23    18    25     2    22

Answer (score 0):

```
 result = max(a-triu(inf(size(a)),1),[],1)
```